# Como transformar valores de um array em variáveis PHP para consulta no BD?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estou precisando muito de qualquer ajuda de vocês com um probleminha em PHP/MySQL.

Tenho uma variável que possui os nomes de medicamentos separados por vírgulas (string), a quantidade de nomes armazenados nesta variável sempre pode variar, ex:

```
$medicamentos = "remedio1, remedio2, remedio3";
```

Eu pego essa string e separo os medicamentos explodindo as vírgulas:

```
$arrayMed = explode(", ",$medicamentos);
```

Até aí tudo bem, mas como eu pego esses medicamentos já separados vindos deste array pra mim poder fazer uma consulta no BD como no exemplo abaixo?:

```
$ReadMedicamentos = ExeRead("tabela_medicamentos", "WHERE medicamento_nome = '$variavel_vinda_do_array'");
while ($m = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ReadMedicamentos)):  
   extract($m);
endwhile;
```

Preciso que todos os medicamentos deste array sejam buscados no BD.

Obs: Eu uso a função "ExeRead" para fazer consultas no BD usando MySQLi.

Como posso fazer essa consulta no BD para todos os medicamentos que estão presentes no Array?

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Usando seu exemplo `$arrayMed = explode(", ",$medicamentos);` então `$arrayMed[0] === remedio1`, `$arrayMed[1] === remedio2` e `$arrayMed[2] === remedio3`. Então faça `foreach ($arrayMed as $remedio) { sua consulta }`

Comment: Então essa variável "$remedio" que vc colocou ali, vai receber a cada volta do laço de repetição do foreach o nome de um medicamento, isso?
E nesse caso essa variável tomaria o lugar da minha variável ''$variavel_vinda_do_array" que usei no exemplo, isso?

Comment: E nesse caso, posso usar essa variável "$remedio" no lugar da minha variável ''$variavel_vinda_do_array" que usei no exemplo?

Comment: Exato, esse laço foi construído para isso.

Comment: Excelente @AugustoVasques, muito bom mesmo.
Vou testar depois e vejo como ficou.
Mas desde já valeu aí pela atenção.